# Image visible over fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have created a header with `position: fixed` and below that I added a logo using image replacement. However, when I scroll down, the image moves *over* the header rather than *under* it.

How can I get the fixed header to always be on top (i.e. force the images to move under it)?

Here is part of my code:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Work</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="banner">
    <h1><img src="imgs\logo.png" />Jackle</h1>
    <h3>We design and create.</h3>
</div>

<img src="" class="representationBannerPic">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis recusandae ullam dolores sint eligendi voluptatibus incidunt esse vero totam aspernatur. Iste quae molestias sed enim corrupti rerum nam culpa asperiores.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
header
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 47px;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
.banner
{
    background-color: #3b97b1;
    background-color: #5fa1b4;
    height: 247px;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner h1 
{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.banner h1 img
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 60px;
   margin-top: -30px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -100px; /* Half the width */
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

If you need to see more, the entire code can be [found here](http://jsbin.com/uvecap/1/).

Answer (score 17):

Add the following rule to your *header* style:

```
header
{
    /* ... */
    z-index: 99;
}
```

The `z-index` property specifies the overlay order of positioned elements. Elements with a greater `z-index` will therefore always be infront of elements with a lower `z-index`. Setting the `z-index` to a value greater than (or even equal to) 0 sets that element to be on top of non-positioned elements with no `z-index` specified. You could always set it to a value lower than 99, but, it is common practice to avoid potential clashes with other positioned elements.

Comment: It works thanks.Can you explain the reason behind using z-index?

Comment: @Tom z-index works only on elements with `position` different from static (the default value)

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
    z-index: 1;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

It works in every browser with no side effect.