# I added some CSS to get a sticky header but scrolling down pictures cover the header

Tags: css, sticky

I tryed to get a sticky header for my website https://sacconicase.com/case-vacanza/lignano-sabbiadoro-appartamenti-vacanze/

I found some CSS

```
#masthead {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

it works but not completely: when I scroll down the pictures cover the header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image visible over fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667784/image-visible-over-fixed-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property to `#masthead` to make its z-position higher than the images. Give `masthead` a `z-index` of 1 or higher to make it be above the other images.

*z-index of 0*
[image: Screenshot of a website with various images of apartments. Two of the images jut into the header with portions of the images above the header.]

*z-index of 1*
[image: Screenshot of the same website with the header problem fixed; the images no longer appear above the header.]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `position: relative` on your images and that should work